# Salesforce Touch Development controls download?

Tags: touch

Can some provide some useful links for the starting development in sales force touch platform?

I have already setup, sales force mobile sdk in eclipse setup, but I want to work on sales force touch

How to download the controls for the mobile development, also some tutorial examples for the starting the touch development?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Salesforce Touch Platform](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Salesforce_touch_platform) is the next-generation platform that powers Salesforce's mobile applications and enables enterprises to build their own iPad, iPhone, and Android applications.

According to Salesforce's documentation:

> **Recommended Learning Path**
>
> [*The
>   Salesforce Touch Platform - Mobile Development Guide*](http://media.developerforce.com/pdfs/salesforce_touch_platform.pdf) contains
>   everything you need to get started developing mobile apps in the
>   cloud. From architectural considerations to deployments, this is your
>   one-stop shop for mobile development. We made it quick and easy by
>   giving you template projects, sample apps that you can modify, and
>   lots of code. When your app is up and running on mobile devices, there
>   are advanced topics on caching data offline, geolocation, using the
>   camera, and more. Download the PDF and get started today!

[image: Salesforce Touch Platform]

You can also [request a hard copy](https://www.salesforce.com/form/offer/touch-platform-book.jsp?d=70130000000sqs7&internal=true&display_type=lb&contentWidth=740&contentPadding=30) if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Can some provide some useful links for case study "the sales force learning"?
"the sales force learning" and "the sales learning curve" are the same or not?